# Live video streaming, how to play it on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am wondering what is available to play live video feed on my iPhone, in a developer way.
Few apps exists and play live stream like :

> http://qik.com/
> http://www.ustream.tv
> http://orb.com/en/orblive

Do you have an idea how they achieve this ?

Thanks a lot.

Thierry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883804/writing-an-iphone-application-with-embedded-video

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 3.0 software includes new APIs for video streaming. Unfortunately, it's under NDA at the moment, so no one can really talk about it on these forums.

Comment: really ?
I am unable to find it in the 3.0 sdk.

Comment: O'Reilly mentions it in their analysis of the iPhone 3.0 announcement, point #6. http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/analysis---iphone-30-developer.html

Answer (score 0):

I did worked on the live video streaming. Unfortunately, i didn't got any solution regarding this. Till the day apple don't have included the RTSP streaming support in its SDKs. So for now their is not any solution for Live video streaming, may be we may have some in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate ffmpeg & live555 to iOS to achieve live video streaming on iOS.

Here is an open source project:
https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone

In fact, I've tries to migrate ffmpeg 0.6 and live555 to iOS, and made a simple video streaming app. It's totally feasible.

Comment: How you integrate both lib' please give any idea, i am also trying to migrate these two lib but i am not able to do, because i don't know how to intgrate these to lib and from i strat to migrate these lib. please help me. if you have any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have to encode our live streaming into HLS formate such .m3u8,mp4 and any other HLS support formate in iOS.Apple did't approve live streaming without HLS formate.you can use  wowza media server to encode your server url to HLS formate for support in iOS and then you can play it through MPMoviePlayerController in iOS.