# Streaming live video to iPhone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

I am a mobile application developer, and for around 2 weeks I have been researching how to do live streaming to iPhone via some server, but I haven't had any success yet. I have an iPhone application ready to receive live streaming using the `MPMoviePlayerController` class.

Here are my requirements:

1. I have a live .FLV streaming feed URL for some news video channels. I want to pass this to some server software to encode to an iPhone-supported format to stream to my iPhone program.

   I used VLC to stream to the iPhone, but it doesn't work. I used nightly build version 1.2 of VLC that they advertise has iPhone streaming, but it still doesn't work.

   I tried using VLC to Wowza and then to iPhone. It somehow worked after encoding via VLC and segmentation and streaming via Wowza to iPhone, but the trial version only supports up to 3 minutes streaming, so it is useless for giving a demo to my customer.

   *or*
2. I bought a TV Tuner card and I have the analog cable connection network. I want to input this cable connection into the TV Tuner card and then use some software like VLC to stream the channel's feed to the iPhone for most of the channels I get.

I mainly want to stream through either method above to iPhone, Android, and Blackberry devices. As Blackberry and Android support RTSP streaming I don't have much difficulty - I can simply use VLC itself to stream it for all channels at a time. The big headache, however, occurs for iPhone's http streaming.

What server software is available for streaming to iPhone, Android and Blackberry? What software can I buy for my business purposes that would solve either point 1 or point 2?

Could someone please guide me to the right software which can solve my problem: to resolve streaming to iPhone? I am ready to buy the server software. Please note, I have the iPhone and Android application program already able to receive and play the streaming video.

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883804/writing-an-iphone-application-with-embedded-video

Comment: This is entirly wrong answer from Eliben. Look at my actual query, i have already an iPhone and Android streaming application ready, i just need server side part which can stream to my mobile application.

Comment: So your question is basically **how to setup a video stream server**. Since you want it compatible with iPhone, I'd look for **quicktime**.

Comment: May i get the link where i can try and see pricing details etc. for quicktime streaming sever?

Comment: Hi Cawas, i see from internet that QTSS doesn't support for iPhone http streaming. It does only RTSP streaming.

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer is late but it can help other developers.
It worked best for me. The solution is:
Make sure you are member of Apple developer program. Login into your apple account and download
MakeRefMovie software from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=http%20#). Put it on your server. It will open any streaming channel just by giving the link of the channel and it will create .m3u8 file. Access the .m3u8  files from any Apple device and present it through MPMoviePlayerController. Set the URL of MPMoviePlayerController to .m3u8 file on your server. It will work!!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can suggest is orblive for iphone. 
Details can be found here. http://www.orb.com/orblive

Comment: They have a iPhone app already right? I want to develop such an app, so i should use only server right? If i use orblive server, i should use their iPhone app to stream it right? I don't want that, i want to use my own iPhone APP to stream it.That's why i noted in my question clearly that i have already an app for iPhone, need just a streaming server.